# std::getline only reading one line:

Tags: c++

I took some code from http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ in order to read the character data from a file:

```
string line;
ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
if (myfile.is_open()) {
   while ( getline (myfile,line) ) {
       cout << line << '\n';
   }
myfile.close();
}
```

If I create the file with emacs and put in the text data myself, I get exactly what I expected: The entire file is written. But if I try to read in the data from the file I *want* to read, then I only read the first line.

File1.txt, which doesn't work, has the following hex dump (output truncated):

```
0000000   1   9   9   8   0   1   0   2   ,   9   3   6   ,   1   3   .
0000010   3   3   4   5   ,   1   3   .   3   3   4   5   ,   1   3   .
0000020   3   3   4   5   ,   1   3   .   3   3   4   5   ,   1   3   4
0000030   8   9   6   ,   4   ,   0   ,   5  \r   1   9   9   8   0   1
0000040   0   2   ,   9   3   7   ,   1   3   .   3   3   4   5   ,   1
0000050   3   .   3   4   5   7   ,   1   3   .   3   3   4   5   ,   1
0000060   3   .   3   4   5   7   ,   1   4   9   8   8   .   5   ,   4
0000070   ,   0   ,   0  \r
```

File2.txt (which does work) has the following hex dump:

```
0000000   1   4   0   3   8   0   ,       3   2   5   0   0   ,       2
0000010   1   4   0   1   4  \n   1   3   1   3   4   ,               2
0000020   3   4   8   ,       2   3   4   .   0   2   3   ,  \n   1   2
0000030   3   4   ,               1   2   3   4   8   ,       1   2   3
0000040   .   3   9   2   4  \n
```

So clearly one file has a different end-of-line char than the other, but how can I get past this? I'm using MacOSX.

Comment: No idea.  I ran your code locally on my Linux box without issues.

Comment: `\n` isn't actually a character you can see in a hex dump etc, as it resolves differently per OS.  I'm not sure if it would cause trouble, but I'd check whether you have a linefeed line ending convention in your input file, but `getline()` on your OS is expecting carriage returns too?  Or it may be that the file embeds NULs and given you've opened it in text mode rather than binary, maybe it causes trouble?  What does `line` actually have in it - the entire file content?  What you consider the first line?  Up until some other character?  That's a big clue.  Would help if you showed in/output.

Comment: We need to see a sample of the input file causing the problem.

Comment: Especially the `hexdump`.  Also, what OS you're using.

Comment: @TonyD I'm not sure I understand why you think a `\n` char can't be seen in a hex dump.  A linefeed, `\n`, is 0x0a and a carriage return, `\r` is 0x0d.

Comment: It looks like `file1.txt` uses old school Macintosh line endings (Carriage Return).

Comment: What is tr \r \t supposed to do?

Comment: @NickThompson: you can probably get help about a command by using the `--help` option, like `tr --help`. you need to be critically attentive to details when using commands. it doesn't do to get even a single character wrong, as you did in your question comment.

Comment: If you know that your input files are using `\r` as line separator, you can specify `'\r'` as third argument in your `getline` command to make it work.

Comment: @CareyGregory: my point is that in C++ I/O `\n` doesn't necessarily designate a linefeed - in Windows for example, it will create/match a carriage-return/line-feed sequence.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages

Comment: Sadly, `std::getline` doesn't support a set of delimiters, so if you need to detect and parse files in either format you may need to scan forwards through the file to recognise the line termination convention, then seeking back to the beginning and use `while (getline(...))`.

Comment: @TonyD Understood about C++, but a hex dump doesn't care about C and C++ and Windows and such.  A hex dump of a file is (or should be) precisely the bytes in the file.

Comment: @CareyGregory: so?  Whatever program generates the text dump generates an arbitrary representation... it can of course use the text "\n" for a linefeed if it wants to, and it appears that Nick's tool did (he edited in his dumps after my comment btw)... it would be more unambiguously meaningful for the tool to use LF or \012 or \0x0A though....

Comment: @TonyD (shrug) The OP chose to use a dump utility that interprets hex values and assigns them symbols such as `\n` rather than simply printing the value of the bytes it finds in the file.  Flawed utility, on that I think we agree.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Yes - his tool did that, and I agree it's flawed! :-)  My statement "`\n` isn't actually a character you can see in a hex dump" means that if a C++ program outputs `\n`, the bytes written vary so you can't *portably* recognise the `\n` in the data file, nor - therefore - the dump.  Similarly, `getline` terminating at "`\n`" may need different input bytes per OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\r is not the default delimiter.

You can set the delimiter for "getline", in the third argument.

```
getline (myfile,line, '\r');
```